# slurm:all cpus in a node are allocated by a job which just need a subset of cpus

Tags: mpi, slurm

I have every node configured as follow in slurm.conf

```
NodeName=node1 NodeAddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   State=UNKNOWN Procs=32 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=2 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=128000  TmpDisk=65536
```

when I run the following command

```
srun -n 2 sleep 60
```

I found that all the core in a node would be allocated by this job. If another job want to run on this node, it would be bolcked until the previous job finishes.

scontrol show the job information as following

```
JobId=51 JobName=sleep
UserId=hadoop(1002) GroupId=hadoop(1002) MCS_label=N/A
Priority=4294901703 Nice=0 Account=hadoop QOS=normal
JobState=RUNNING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=0 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
RunTime=00:00:12 TimeLimit=UNLIMITED TimeMin=N/A
SubmitTime=2018-07-16T21:46:56 EligibleTime=2018-07-16T21:46:56
StartTime=2018-07-16T21:46:56 EndTime=Unknown Deadline=N/A
PreemptTime=None SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0
LastSchedEval=2018-07-16T21:46:56
Partition=TOTAL AllocNode:Sid=node1:25124
ReqNodeList=(null) ExcNodeList=(null)
NodeList=xxx.xxx.xxx
BatchHost=xxx.xxx.xxx
NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=32 NumTasks=2 CPUs/Task=1 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
TRES=cpu=32,mem=125G,node=1,billing=32
Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=0:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
MinCPUsNode=1 MinMemoryNode=125G MinTmpDiskNode=0
Features=(null) DelayBoot=00:00:00
Gres=(null) Reservation=(null)
OverSubscribe=NO Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
Command=sleep
WorkDir=/home/hadoop
Power=
```

Use sacct to get the history jobs , I get the following output

```
       JobID    JobName  Partition    Account  AllocCPUS      State ExitCode
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
       51       sleep      TOTAL     hadoop         32    COMPLETED  0:0
       51.0     sleep                hadoop          2    COMPLETED  0:0
```

show the partition information:

```
  PartitionName=TOTAL
  AllowGroups=ALL AllowAccounts=ALL AllowQos=ALL
  AllocNodes=ALL Default=YES QoS=N/A
  DefaultTime=NONE DisableRootJobs=NO ExclusiveUser=NO GraceTime=0 
  Hidden=NO
  MaxNodes=UNLIMITED MaxTime=UNLIMITED MinNodes=1 LLN=NO 
  MaxCPUsPerNode=UNLIMITED
  Nodes=xxxxxxx
  PriorityJobFactor=1 PriorityTier=1 RootOnly=NO ReqResv=NO OverSubscribe=NO
  OverTimeLimit=NONE PreemptMode=OFF
  State=UP TotalCPUs=96 TotalNodes=3 SelectTypeParameters=NONE
  DefMemPerNode=UNLIMITED MaxMemPerNode=UNLIMITED
```

It seems something wrong.

Comment: via `scontrol show partition TOTAL`, you can double check your partition is not configured exclusive(e.g. only one job per node). an other option is the node is full because you requested/allocated **all** the memory so there is no room for an other job (even if some CPUs are sitting idle)

Comment: I found this log in slurmcltd.log:_valid_pn_min_mem: job 74 memory per node set to 128000M in partition TOTAL

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem casued by SelectType. I let it as the default value which I think is select/linear. As mentioned in [Select Plugin Design Guide](https://slurm.schedmd.com/select_design.html), select/linear is node-centric .

> The select/linear and select/cons_res plugins have similar modes of operation. The obvious difference is that data structures in select/linear are node-centric, while those in select/cons_res contain information at a finer resolution (sockets, cores, threads, or CPUs depending upon the SelectTypeParameters configuration parameter).

I change SelectType to  select/cons_res and restart the whole cluster, the problem is solved.